# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn behaves differently on Windows 7+ OS

Tags: winforms, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I've made a client application in Windows Forms. I've used Windows Server 2008 R2 for development.

However client has reported few bugs which I am not able to reproduce on my machine but when I deploy same solution on Windows 7 or 10. It gives me different results.

As of now I now two problems:

1. `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` backcolour turns out to be gray.
2. When moving across the columns using Tabs or Cursors keys, they skip combo box column. **This is biggest problem.**

I've created a test application with minimal code and found that this problem persists with test app as well.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
{
    column.HeaderText = "CB";
    column.Name = "CB";
    column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    //column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    column.DataSource = list;
    column.ValueType = typeof(string);

}

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtEmp;
```

Here is screenshot of problem:

**Windows 10 - Notice that despite moving cursor key, first column is not highlighted**
[image]
**Windows 2008- Notice that dfirst column is highlighted and cells are not grayed out.**
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to change [DisplayStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaystyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to `Nothing` enum value so that your column will by styled and focus will be visible. However combobox arrow obviously disappears, but that might not be an issue for you.

```
this.Column1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
```

[image: Result]

Or try to change [FlatStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.flatstyle(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to `Flat` so that you will see a combo box arrow:

```
this.Column1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
```

[image: Flat]

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm
this.Column1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;